# How to tune store step on Wercker

Tags: continuous-integration, wercker

When I run build on Wercker it is failed because I get error at store step:

> Size exceeds maximum size of 1000MB

How can I *disable store step* or *increase store size* ?

This is part of `wercker.yml`:

```
box: java

build:
  steps:
    - script:
        name: create test db
        code: |
          sudo apt-get install -y percona-server-server-5.6
          sudo service mysql start
          #sql to create db

    - script:
        name: install gradle
        code: |
          wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
          unzip gradle-2.8-all.zip

    - script:
        name: gradle build
        code: |
          gradle-2.8/bin/gradle clean build --stacktrace
```

Comment: What sort of app are you building? Can you post some of the `wercker.yml` file so we can see what you're making and work out why it's so big?

Comment: @ocean I build Java application. I added `wercker.yml` to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the Wercker "store" step enabled? It's normally used mainly to debug your build process (by allowing you to download and inspect the build container afterwards). I don't think there's a way of increasing the size, but you can certainly turn it off, by removing the:

```
- internal/store-container
```

step from your `wercker.yml`.

One of the things that will be contributing to your large container size is that you're installing Percona MySQL internally to your container, when the recommended practice would be to use a Wercker local service for that.

Check the [Wercker local services documentation](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/services/advanced-services.html) for more information.

Comment: how to use Percona as aervice? [Here](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/services/) I didn't find Percona as supported service.

Comment: I haven't `- internal/store-container` step in my `wercker.yml` but nevertheless I have `store` step on build page. Is `store` step is default Wercker step?

Comment: A service is just a call to a docker container. There's more info on configuring services at http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/services/linking-services.html and you could probably use the Percona one from https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/

Comment: Ah yes, maybe you can't stop that store step at the end. I know other have used Wercker to build Java apps (which are often large), so it must be possible to do without hitting the 1GB barrier. Have you tried asking on the Wercker Slack channel?

Comment: yes, I asked on Wercker Slack and they advised me to delete folders from `$WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR`. So I decided to delete all Java build artifacts using this script:
`- script:
        name: remove node_modules folder from output
        code: find $WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR -name "*.jar" -type f -delete`